# SimpleJdbcCall Oracle Stored Procedure Wrong number or types of arguments

Tags: java, oracle, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am trying to call a Oracle Stored Procedure with one output cursor type parameter and no input parameters. While am able to successfully run the stored procedure using vanilla jdbc, I am getting

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
>   'MYPROCEDURE'

error when using Spring's SimpleJdbcCall API. Am not able to figure out where am doing wrong, could somebody help me understand what's wrong in the below code? Procedure/Parameter names/types are all spelled properly.

```
DataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(); //has jdbcurl,username,password,driverClassName set
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                                 .withSchemaName("myschema")
                                  .withCatalogName("mypackage")
                                   .withProcedureName("myprocedure")
                                    .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
                                     .withReturnValue()
                                      .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("out_param_name", OracleTypes.Cursor, new MyRowMapper());
Map<String,Object> result = jdbcCall.execute();
```

Comment: Add the procedure code also.

Comment: Can't add procedure code. Like I said above, procedure code is proper as I am able to successfully call and get the data back from the procedure using plain jdbc

Comment: You will need to reproduce this problem with a procedure which you can post the code of.